# linq version of a query with let operator

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have this such query :

```
SELECT au_lname,der.col FROM authors INNER JOIN (SELECT t.au_id, COUNT(title_id) AS 'col'
                       FROM titleauthor t GROUP BY t.au_id) der ON authors.au_id=der.au_id
```

I want write this with `let` operator.How I can do this?

thanks

Comment: *Why* do you want to write this with a let operator?

Comment: I want to learn 'let' operator.I hear that 'let' will convert to derived tables in output sql and I want to see what is difference between my query and output query.please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no good reason to use `let` here. You can just use a group join.

```
var query = from author in authors
            join title in titleAuthor on author.AuthorId equals title.AuthorId
            into titles
            where titles.Count() != 0
            select new { author.LastName, Count = titles.Count() };
```

You *could* use `let` for the count here, I suppose:

```
var query = from author in authors
            join title in titleAuthor on author.AuthorId equals title.AuthorId
            into titles
            let count = titles.Count()
            where count != 0
            select new { author.LastName, Count = count };
```

Or you could use a more direct translation of your original query:

```
var innerQuery = from title in titleAuthor
                 group title by title.AuthorId into titles
                 select new { AuthorId = titles.Key, Count = titles.Count() };
var query = from author in authors
            join titleCount in innerQuery
              on author.AuthorId equals titleCount.AuthorId
            select new { author.AuthorId, titleCount.Count };
```

Comment: thanks dear @Jon but I compare `join` version of above query with `derived table` version and see `derived table` version cost is 48% and I want to write my query in way that use `derived table`

Comment: See my edit for an alternative which is closer to your original query. Note that the LINQ execution style makes it cheap to split queries up like this.

Comment: thanks dear @Jon. Can you please explain more about third query.that was great.

Comment: @Kerezo: Well it's pretty much a direct translation of your original... what don't you understand about it?

Comment: Sorry yes I don't see linq query like that before.I wonder how `.Net` know what to do for translate it to Sql version. why you split query in 2 query.thanks dear @jon.You are great

Comment: @Kerezo: The SQL query provider does all the magic. I split it into two queries just for readability - I prefer not to have nested queries, and the way LINQ works makes it easy to split them up.